# snd_aloop module: no sound in pavucontrol meters or in obs, but sound in audacity... why?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using DroidCam on NixOs, and this software uses the snd_aloop module to send the phones microphone (and video) to a computer. When I run it, everything works fine, except that the snd_aloop sink behave in a quite strange and annoying way:

1. on Audacity, I can configure the input to be "Alsa/Loopback: PCM(hw:0,1)" and everything works well, i.e. I can record the sound from the phone (confirmed by the fact that if I put the phone under some pillow, the sounds becomes very quiet)
2. but on pavucontrol meter, and if I try to add this sink from OBS studio for example, I can't see any sound going out of the snd_aloop sink (that, btw, appears as a second Internal Stereo Analog sink)

Any idea why the pavucontrol meter/OBS Studio can't get the sound from the snd_aloop device, while Audacity can get the loopback?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that in order to make pulseaudio aware of the alsa device, one need to do (replace eventually the device name):

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:Loopback,1,0
```